# How do I restore .bat association on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, batch-file, file-association

I have accidentally set the association for .bat files to notepad. This was done by going to the Default Programs panel and setting it to run with notepad. I've tried everything I can find on this subject. I've deleted the USER CHOICE option in regedit, I've tried merging with the reg file, I've tried multiple association restoration programs, I've removed the association all together, and it has not worked. No matter what I try, it will open in notepad or ask for a program to open in. I'm not sure if there is a program it opens in by default, but I could really use some help. I've been researching and trying everything for a week with no progress towards a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the following **.reg** file as administrator, then manually delete the following key manually:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.BAT\UserChoice
```

**Run reg file as admin:**

```
runas /user:administrator "regedit /s c:\fix.reg"
```

**Reg file:**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile]
@="Windows Batch File"
"EditFlags"=hex:30,04,00,00
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
  32,00,5c,00,61,00,63,00,70,00,70,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
  00,2c,00,2d,00,36,00,30,00,30,00,32,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,69,00,6d,00,\
  61,00,67,00,65,00,72,00,65,00,73,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,2d,00,36,\
  00,38,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\edit]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\edit\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4e,00,4f,00,\
  54,00,45,00,50,00,41,00,44,00,2e,00,45,00,58,00,45,00,20,00,25,00,31,00,00,\
  00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open]
"EditFlags"=hex:00,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\print]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\print\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,4e,00,4f,00,\
  54,00,45,00,50,00,41,00,44,00,2e,00,45,00,58,00,45,00,20,00,2f,00,70,00,20,\
  00,25,00,31,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runas]
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runas\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,63,00,6d,00,\
  64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,2f,00,43,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,\
  00,20,00,25,00,2a,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runasuser]
@="@shell32.dll,-50944"
"Extended"=""
"SuppressionPolicyEx"="{F211AA05-D4DF-4370-A2A0-9F19C09756A7}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runasuser\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{ea72d00e-4960-42fa-ba92-7792a7944c1d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers]
@="Compatibility"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\Compatibility]
@="{1d27f844-3a1f-4410-85ac-14651078412d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\OpenGLShExt]
@="{E97DEC16-A50D-49bb-AE24-CF682282E08D}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\DropHandler]
@="{86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\PropertySheetHandlers\ShimLayer Property Page]
@="{513D916F-2A8E-4F51-AEAB-0CBC76FB1AF8}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\ShellEx\{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}]
@="{1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22}"
```

Comment: I've run the command prompt as administrator and done the line of code, but it still says "the requested operation requires elevation". I know I'm running the command prompt as administrator as it says "Administrator: Command Prompt" above it.